SOMU randomTrips did not generate
I have some issues with SOMU randomTrips and I do not find anything useful on web, so I should ask, please help me...
senario:
0- I made a map.xml with a small area.
1- I ran command prompt in this folder to make random trips. when I run randomTrips command randomTrips file has been opened in visual studio(python file) and command prompt wants to get something that can not do this.
I have any idea
my python version is => 3.11.4
my SOMU version is => 1.19.0

